# How to locate a small section in JSON that differs from other values

Tags: java, json, selenium

I am currently trying to run a script, within Selenium using Java, that does not know which page loads.  There is a JSON field that is embedded into it that I am trying to use to tell my script which section has loaded to run the right test.  The problem is that all the JSON values are the same except a section of one of the fields.

Below are the three JSON values pulled:

```
    value="{"formType":"taskExecutuion","orderId":"111111","userId":"222","assigneeId":"333","taskId":"44444","taskName":"Order Entry Review by Listing","taskDisplayName":"AAAA 1234569999 Same for All Test 1 Fulfillment 666666"}"

value="{"formType":"taskExecutuion","orderId":"111111","userId":"222","assigneeId":"333","taskId":"44444","taskName":"Order Entry Review by Listing","taskDisplayName":"AAAA 1234569999 Same for All Test 2 Fulfillment 666666"}"

value="{"formType":"taskExecutuion","orderId":"111111","userId":"222","assigneeId":"333","taskId":"44444","taskName":"Order Entry Review by Listing","taskDisplayName":"AAAA 1234569999 Same for All Test 3 Fulfillment 666666"}"
```

The only difference found is the number between Test and Fulfillment in the taskDisplayName.

I am currently trying to use the following method to run in the order they load:

```
int spr = 0;

do {
Thread.sleep(10000);

WebElement task_name = driver.findElement(By.xpath("id('test')"));
String task_name_values = task_name.getAttribute("value");

Object obj = null;
try {
    obj = parser.parse(task_name_values);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
JSONObject fulfill = (JSONObject)obj;

String fulfillment_form_confirm = (String) fulfill.get("taskDisplayName");

if (fulfillment_form_confirm.contains("Test 1")){
    testRun.testSample1(driver);
} else if (fulfillment_form_confirm.contains("Test 2")){
    testRun.testSample2(driver);
} else if (fulfillment_form_confirm.contains("Test 3")){            
    testRun.testSample3(driver);
} else break;
spr++;
System.out.print(spr + "\n");
} while (spr == 2);
```

If anyone can help me figure out why it skips right past all three and goes to the next test after these three without even looking I would appreciate it.

Ran script with:

```
System.out.println(fulfillment_form_confirm);
```

inserted and this is the value that was returned:

AAAA 1234569999 Same for All Test 1 Fulfillment  666666

Interesting to note that it did register the first time through the do while loop but then exited without going through the other two times like it should have

Comment: do a `System.out.println(fulfillment_form_confirm);` and post what it returns

Comment: You could skip the whole JSON parsing thing and just look for "Test (\d+) Fulfillment" using regex and then fork based on the returned digit.

Comment: unsure how to do that